# Query updating entire table

Tags: database, ms-access

This is the query i have within my database

```
UPDATE NewCustomer INNER JOIN ACTList ON NewCustomer.NewProvider<>ACTList.Provider SET       NewCustomer.Status = "Denied Not Freemail";
```

As you can see the only records that should be updated are the ones where the NewCustomer.Provider is not equal to the ACTList.Provider but it is actually updating all of the fields.

Can someone tell me why this is?

Comment: Did any of the supplied answers help?  If so, you should upvote one or more that did and accept one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
UPDATE NewCustomer 
SET NewCustomer.Status = "Denied Not Freemail"
FROM NewCustomer INNER JOIN ACTList 
WHERE NewCustomer.NewProvider<>ACTList.Provider;
```

Comment: Doesn't INNER JOIN need an ON clause?

Comment: Its saying that there is a missing operator

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot (untested).  It basically says `WHERE NewCustomer.NewProvider NOT IN ()`, but more efficiently.

```
UPDATE NewCustomer 
  SET NewCustomer.Status = "Denied Not Freemail"
LEFT JOIN ACTList ON NewCustomer.NewProvider = ACTList.Provider 
WHERE ACTList.Provider IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have selects all rows because each row is not equal to at least one row in ActList. You can use an outer join and check for nulls.

```
UPDATE NewCustomer LEFT JOIN ACTList ON NewCustomer.NewProvider = ACTList.Provider SET NewCustomer.Status = "Denied Not Freemail"
WHERE (((ACTList.Provider) Is Null));
```